# Wrapping numpy slices using super().take in narray subclass

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclass

I am attempting to subclass a numpy array in order to create arrays that have periodic boundary conditions. I only need this to work for 1D arrays.

**What I Want**:
Suppose I have an object `a=Periodic_Grid([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`. I would like the following outputs

```
>>> a=Periodic_Grid(a)
>>> a
Periodic_Grid([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[0]
0
>>> a[7]
7
>>> a[14]
4
>>> a[-5]
5
>>> a[-14]
6
>>> a[1:5]
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
>>> a[8:13]
array([8., 9., 0., 1., 2.])
>>> a[-5:2]
array([5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 0., 1.])
```

In other words, indexing just wraps around. Slicing should also appropriately wrap around. Otherwise, it acts as normal.

**Minimal Working Code**

```
class Periodic_Grid(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.grid_size = input_array.size
        return obj 

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            indicies=list(range(index.start, index.stop))
            size=len(indicies)
            a=np.empty(size)
            print("Size: {0} indicies: {1}".format(size, indicies))
            for i, ind in enumerate(indicies): 
                idx=self.wrapped_index(ind)
                a[i]=self[idx]
            return a

        elif isinstance(index, tuple):
            idx=index[0]
            idx=self.wrapped_index(idx)
            return super().__getitem__(idx)
        elif isinstance(index, int):
            index = self.wrapped_index(index)
            return super().__getitem__(index)
        else:
            print("RAISING EXCEPTION")
            raise ValueError

    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        index = self.wrapped_index(index)
        return super().__setitem__(index, item)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.grid_size = getattr(obj, 'grid_size', obj.size)
        pass

    def wrapped_index(self, index):
        idx=None
        #if hasattr(index, '__iter__'): idx=
        if type(index) is tuple:
            idx=index[0] #only support for 1D!
        elif type(index) is int:
            idx=index
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unexpected index: {}'.format(index))
```

**My Question**

The above code actually works well, so in that sense my problem is solved. However, I have a question about how I have implemented handling slices in `__getitem__`. In the above code, I have resorted to using a loop and manually looping over the needing indices and filling the appropriate values. This occurs in a Python loop, whereas I would like to let `numpy` handle this loop if possible. I think this should be possible using numpy.take like so (looking just at the block of `__getitem__` that handles slice objects:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
     if isinstance(index, slice):
         start=index.start
         stop=index.stop
         indices=list(range(start, stop))
         return super().take(self, indices, mode='wrap')
```

However, now I run into an error:

```
>>> b[1:5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "path/to/class/file", line 130, in __getitem__
    return super().take(self, indices, mode='wrap')
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

As far as I can tell however, passing a list of indices to `take` is allowed, judging by the first example in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take). I have suspicions that I am using `super()` wrong but I am not sure. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a class with an attribute: array = [1, ..., N] and have a method to access elements using any index, but with modulo N instead? like `return a[N+1%N]`. Slicing might be a bit tricky. There is also the case `a[0:N+1]`, should it return an array with N+2 elements (you did not discuss it in your example)?

Comment: I considered such an approach and might change gears if this doesn't work out. And yes, a[0:N+1] should return an array of N+2 elements.

Comment: `take` isn't a method.  It's a numpy function that takes the array as argument.  It looks like with your way of calling it, `indices` is the 3rd argument, which it interprets as `axis`.

Comment: @gabe There are two versions of `take`. The one you want is here. So first thing is to replace super().take(self, ...)` by `np.take(self, ...)`https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take. You need to have the array in question in the first argument. You probably need to create it like you did before and fill it with the right numbers.